# Adding an src from an API in Angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my component.ts where when it's loaded I get the data from the api, which I can see in the console.log, I do infact get my array of 10 objects (they come in groups of 10 on the api). I have the correct path in the API for the source code of the first image in the array of 10 which I typed to out the correct path for in normal http/javascript format of data.hits.hits[n]._source.images[n].urls.original. However when I try to put it in angular it can't read the data value as it is right now since it's out of scope, but I can't figure out how to word it in a better way.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../../config.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-binding',
  templateUrl: './property-binding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-binding.component.css']
})
export class PropertyBindingComponent implements OnInit {

  private isHidden : boolean;

  public zeroImage : string;

  private Photos : Observable<Object>;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //doing the API call
    this.Photos = this.configService.getConfig();
    this.Photos.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }


  toggle() : void {
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;

    if(this.isHidden){
    
      //var zeroImg = document.createElement("img");

      this.zeroImage.src = data.hits.hits[0]._source.images[0].urls.original;


    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Angular html page that should property bind the src with the variable that I want.

```
<p>
  View Artworks
</p>
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="toggle()">Show Artwork</button>
<div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="isHidden">
  <img [src]="zeroImage">
</div>
```

Here is the service method that I have the method that makes the API call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'ApiKey': 'my_personal_key'
    })
  };

  private configUrl = 'https://api.art.rmngp.fr/v1/works';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getConfig(){
    let obs = this.http.get(this.configUrl, this.httpOptions)

    console.log("Inside the getConfig method, before subscribe, doing API call" + 
    obs);

    //might not need to subscribe here??
    //obs.subscribe((response) => console.log(response))
    return obs;
    //return this.http.get(this.configUrl, this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

And slightly unrelated code, this is the normal http/javascript where I wrote the code Outside of Angular, which works perfectly fine.

```
function displayPhoto(){
        
        fetch('https://api.art.rmngp.fr/v1/works/, {headers: {ApiKey: "my_personal_key"}})
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){   
            document.getElementById("zeroImg").src = data.hits.hits[0]._source.images[0].urls.original;
```

Again, the API call in Angular works, I can see I am pulling the data successfully, I however can not set the image to the first image in the set of data and have been struggling with it. any help will help

Comment: It looks like you're binding to a property that does not exist. The binding says `<img [src]="zeroImg">`, but the property in your component is `public zeroImage : string`. Or am I missing somthing here?

Comment: Shouldn't you also have something like this: `this.Photos.subscribe((data) => console.log(data); this.data = data;);` to actually capture the data that your API returns and that is then referenced in toggle() as `this.data`?

Comment: @mbj that is right but it doesn't solve the main issue, I was just attempting to solve it in different ways and I guess I forgot to change it back before posting, I will edit the code to represent the correct values of [src]

Comment: @AndrWeisR not sure what you mean there, adding this.data = data;); to the end of the line doesn't really do anything, as it can't read the data variable there either

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the data when you subscribe

```
this.Photos.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

You have not done anything with the data here.

```
zeroImg.src = data.hits.hits[0]._source.images[0].urls.original;
```

zeroImg is a string and makes no sense to set a src property on it and data is undefined at the point. The only place there is a data variable is in your subscription function but it is not available here.

The following will set the src of the image

```
this.Photos.subscribe((data) => {
    this.zeroImg = data.hits.hits[0]._source.images[0].urls.original;
});
```

Make the toggle function just toggle the isHidden flag and get rid of the rest.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //doing the API call
    this.Photos = this.configService.getConfig();
    this.Photos.subscribe((data) => {
      this.zeroImg = data.hits.hits[0]._source.images[0].urls.original;
    });
  }

  toggle() : void {
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quest reply, I went ahead and did that as it makes perfect sense to me that I would need to be inside the subscribe function in order to access the data. I also changed zeroImg from a string to type "any". however now I am getting an error that says the first "hits" does not exist on type Object

Comment: I figured out the issue, for some reason I needed to change this.Photo from an Observable<Object> to Observable<any> and it fixed the issue